# Pronoun: what does it refer to here?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, descriptive-grammar, it-its-itself

In the following sentence, what does the pronoun ***it*** refer to?

> A differs from B in that *it* is....

I read before that a pronoun refers to the closest name (B in that sentence); however, here it makes more sense that the pronoun it refer to A (not B).

I am totally confused when I read that sentence in an article. Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: You might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also, you might find the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

*A* is the subject of the sentence, and *it* is its pronoun, so *it* is A. In other words, the sentence *could* have been written as "A differs from B in that A is," but it's more elegant to use the pronoun "it," instead. Incidentally, "it" is not a preposition; it's a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to A, the subject of the sentence. "B" is an object that receives an action from A. The pronoun refers to the subject, not the object. At least that's my take on it. There may be other ways to parse and describe the grammar. It would be better (unambiguous, at least) to write, "A differs from B in that A is (whatever)..."

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're talking about A.  So the *it* refers to A.  Consider this alternate phrasing:

> B is X.  A differs in that it is Y.

Here, you can clearly see that *it* refers to A.

By inserting the prepositional phrase *from B*, we're not changing the subject so *it* still refers to A:

> A differs (from B) in that it is Y.

You might find [this description](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/proref.htm) helful:

> A pronoun should refer clearly to one, clear, unmistakable noun coming before the pronoun.  This noun is called the pronoun’s antecedent.

So in this case, based on context, the antecedent is clearly A.  (The *in that* indicates that what comes next is a description of how A differs.)